# What Regex would capture both the beginning and end from of a string?

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I am trying to edit a DateTime string in typescript file.
The string in question is `02T13:18:43.000Z`.
I want to trim the first three characters including the letter T from the beginning of a string AND also all 5 characters from the end of the string, that is `Z000.`, including the dot character. Essentialy I want the result to look like this: `13:18:43`.

From what I found the following pattern `(^(.*?)T)` can accomplish only the first part of the trim I require, that leaves the initial result like this: `13:18:43.000Z`. 
What kind of Regex pattern must I use to include the second part of the trim I have mentioned? I have tried to include the following block in the same pattern `(Z000.)$` but of course it failed.
Thanks.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `(\d{2}:){2}\d{2}` to match `00:00:00` pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use regular expression in order to achieve that. You can simply use:

```
let value = '02T13:18:43.000Z';
let newValue = value.slice(3, -5);
console.log(newValue);
```

it will return 13:18:43, assumming that your string will always have the same pattern. According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) slice method will substring from beginIndex to endIndex. endIndex is optional.

Comment: Thanks, that did it, i forgot about the slice function of javascript completely:-)

Comment: Yeah, I did, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

This should suffice to remove both the prefix from beginning to `T` and postfix from `.` to end:

```
/^.*T|\..*$/g
```

```js
console.log(new Date().toISOString().replace(/^.*T|\..*$/g, ''))
```

See the visualization on [debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/wveiYhGpTmyk2j8K)

#### Explanation

The section `^.*T` removes all characters up to and including the last encountered `T` in the string.

The section `\..*$` removes all characters from the first encountered `.` to the end of the string.

The `|` in between coupled with the global `g` flag allows the regular expression to match both sections in the string, allowing `.replace(..., '')` to trim both simultaneously.

Comment: Would someone mind explaining why this would be downvoted? I'd be happy to improve my answer sufficiently, given an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

as I see you only need regex solution so does this pattern work?

`(\d{2}:)+\d{2}` or simply `\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}`

it searches much times for digit-digit-doubleDot combos and digit-digit-doubleDot at the end

the only disadvange is that it doesn't check whether say there are no minutes>59 and etc.

The main reason why I didn't include checking just because I kept in mind that you get your dates from sources where data that are stored are already valid, ex. database.